# Python find.all [BeautifulSoup] suddenly returns empty

Tags: python, web-scraping

A couple of months ago I made my first script ever, which wrote me a message on WhatsApp if a teacher was sick, for that it took all informations from a website, on which our school posts if there is a change in our timetable, which looks like this -> https://prnt.sc/qlir58 <-.

So what i did was basically webscraping, after which i just filtered out the important stuff.
The script worked a couple months without any problems, but suddenly it stopped working.
The reason why it stopped working is, that it suddenly returned a class which i searched via find_all empty. I don't know why my script is returning it empty, because the class exist.

If i write `print(page)` I get this

```
'''    https://pastebin.com/zQFkx73T    '''
```

If I write `print(post_feed)` I just get

```
[]
```

---

```
#login
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.open("a long login link")

browser.select_form('form[action="login site"]')

browser["username"] = "my username"
browser["password"] = "my password"


browser.submit_selected()

#web scraping
page = browser.get_current_page()

post_feed = page.find_all('div', {'class': ['section print-nobreak']})
```